# Why are heap trees always complete binary trees or almost complete binary trees?

Tags: binary-tree, heap

Is it a necessary condition? or can we have a minheap heap like this?

```
     2
    / \
   5   6
      / \
     8   11
```

Answer (score 1):

A binary heap can be (and usually is) implemented as an array, listing the values in *level order*. Only when the tree is an (almost) complete tree, this array does not have "gaps". For the example you have given, the corresponding array representation would be:

```
[2, 5, 6, null, null, 8, 11]
```

These `null` values are annoying and have an impact on the algorithms for insert/delete.

In the standard case (without `null`) these algorithms can easily know the number of children a node has by checking the corresponding indices are out of range. Now they must check whether these indices might refer to `null` values.

The algorithm that walks *down* the tree with a value must consider the possibility of altering a `null` to that value, and the algorithm that carries a value up the tree must consider that trailing `null` values need to be removed (to keep the tree efficient). These are just some of the extra complications that will occur. It is possible, but just slows down the process.

Finally, if the tree's height is not optimised, then it makes the process slower as well as some paths from root to leaf are longer than they would be in an (almost) complete tree.